# React Quill causes rerender of <input> outside of Quill's editor

Tags: reactjs, quill, react-quill

I have the following React code in my component:

```
     const TextEditor = () => {
     const [richTextValue, setRichTextValue] = useState('');
     const [storyTitle, setStoryTitle] = useState('');
        
     const handleRichEditorOnChange = (content, delta, source, editor) => {
                setRichTextValue(editor.getHTML());
     }
        
     const handleTitleChange = event => {
                setStoryTitle(event.target.value);
     }
        
     return (
                    <>
                        <input type="text"
                               placeholder="Title"
                               value={storyTitle}
                               onChange={handleTitleChange}/>
                        <ReactQuill theme="snow"
                                    value={richTextValue}
                                    onChange={handleRichEditorOnChange}/>
                    </>
    )
}
```

If i type anything in `<input>` element, I lose focus after each letter typed because of Quill causing rerender somehow and get the error "Cannot flush updates when React is already rendering". However, if I remove `ReactQuill` element, input's behaviour is normal and I don't receive any error in console.

What is the reason behind this strange and unexpected behaviour and how can it be fixed?

Comment: Each letter you type updates the state of the component. Therefore it is rendered again. If there is a react JSX equivalent for onFocusOut, you can use it to solve the problem to a large extent. In short, try using onFocusOut instead of onChange.

Comment: @Y.C. well, isn't it how we manage input in react anyway? Like, always linking to the component's state.

Comment: maybe just deleting `value={richTextValue}` and `value={storyTitle}` will solve the problem. actually i'm not sure about this. does it solve? :)

Comment: @Y.C. sorry for wasting your time, I got my answer and posted it here :')

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I had:

```
if (richTextEditorRef.current) {
    richTextEditorRef.current.focus();
}
```

in code before adding input and now I figured out that it was forcing React to focus on Quill editor.